# Simulate key presses in C

Tags: c, unix, keyboard

For example, I want to run:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

in C (via `system`) command. But right after I run that, it asks for input:

```
root@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Then I'm expected to type in the password. How can I do this in C code? Could I please get some code on how I could simulate key presses? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a beautiful command [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

This is a common used tool. If you need only for a ssh, you'd better look at other posts for generating a key

Answer (score 4):

There are better ways to do this, such as [key-based SSH authentication](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

This will copy an authorized key to perform ssh commands from your account to root on your own machine.  Future ssh requests won't prompt for a password.  This also means you don't have to include the root password in your shell script.

Another option would be the `sudo` command.  You can add approved commands into the `sudoers` file, including an option to ignore the password requirement for those commands.

Comment: So would the password to the new ssh key be the password of root@172.0.0.1?

Comment: If you don't set a password during the keygen, you don't need a password after you have copied the key.